# Move Legacy system into virtualization

Tags: windows, virtualization, legacy, graphics

I currently have five windows hosts which all have graphics output. I would like to virtualise this setup as it is running on really old hardware and is using little resources by todays standards.

How could I virtualise them and still have them each have one dedicated graphics output such as VGA?

Answer (score 4):

The simpler and more stable approach is to use VNC or RDP to get the guest OS graphical output.

If you **really** needs a physical VGA output, you can use mutiple graphic cards + host passthrough (ie: each video card is passed to the guest OS as-is). However, host passthrough has its own issues and prerequisites, so I suggest against it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Qemu / KVM, Xen HVM, HyperV, VMware, ... there's a lot of solutions to virtualize systems.

Having made your choice, you'll want to look into "P2V" (physical to virtual) migrations. Depending on which hypervisor you would use, the process would vary.